# I cannot get my macro to put a vlookup in each column of row 2

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, formula, vlookup

I currently have two sheets with user data, one is from active directory, the other is from a web based export.

My macro is supposed to place a vlookup function into B2:B24 with the column return going up by one

EG:

```
         Dim beginPosition As Integer

            For beginPosition = 1 To 24
    Range(& beginPosition, "2").Select
    =VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$X$5000,& beginPosition &,FALSE)

Next begin Position
```

Maybe I'm overthinking this and could use somethingn other than Vlookup to grab all the data from my web export sheet, but as of right now i'm stumped.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `Range("B" & beginPosition).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$X$5000,beginPosition,FALSE)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this without looping

```
Range("B1:B24").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet2!$A$1:$X$5000, ROW(),FALSE)"
```

Comment: I also formatted the Formula incorrectly, the end result that worked ended up being:

Range("B2:X2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet2!$A$1:$X$5000, COLUMN(),FALSE)"